# Hide select option before last CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I use this line to hide the last option in a select, I need only CSS:

```
.form-search > select option:last-child {display:none;}
```

how I can do to hide the previous option, the option that is before last?

Can be selected by value? for example the last has 55 value and the option before last has 54 value.
Thank you

Comment: try `.form-search > select option[value="55"] { display: none; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `nth-last-child(2)`.

Like this:

```
.form-search > select option:nth-last-child(2) { display:none; }
```

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child.

This is supported in IE 9+, Chrome 4+, FF 3.5+, Safari 3.2+

Comment: Yes. Ask that in a diff question though and post it here as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.form-search > select option[value="55"] 
{ 
    display: none; 
}
```